# Cómo convertir un string array en pares hexadecimales y completados con ceros a la izquierda

Tags: java, android

Necesito convertir un `string array` en `pares hexadecimales` para cada byte, separados por cero cada par y `completados con ceros a la izquierda` de ser necesario.

Usando mi código obtengo esto:

```
41 54 2B 43 53 51 C A
```

Pero yo necesito esto:

```
41 54 2B 43 53 51 0C 0A
```

Este es mi código:

```
 public class StringToHex {

    public String convertStringToHex(String str) {

        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

        StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            hex.append( Integer.toHexString( (int)  chars[i]).toUpperCase());
            if (hex.length() < 2) {
                hex.insert(1, '0');
            }
            hex.append(" ");
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }
}
```

Pero parece no funcionar, me pueden decir ¿cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un "0" cuando detectes que la longitud del elemento a imprimir es 1:

```
 if(Integer.toHexString( (int)  chars[i]).length()==1){
                hex.append("0");
 }
```

Esto sería realizado de la siguiente forma:

```
public static String convertStringToHex(String str) {

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

        //Agrega un 0 a valores hexadecimales con un digito
        if(Integer.toHexString( (int)  chars[i]).length()==1){
            hex.append("0");
        }

        hex.append( Integer.toHexString( (int)  chars[i]).toUpperCase());        
        if (hex.length() < 2) {
            hex.insert(1, '0');
        }
        hex.append(" ");
    }


    return hex.toString();
}
```

Ejemplo :

```
System.out.println("::" + convertStringToHex("W1ll ?"));
```

Sin el cambio obtendríamos `57 31 6C 6C C 3F` pero ahora la salida sería:

```
57 31 6C 6C 0C 3F
```

Comment: Jorgesys, debe de haber algún error, por que me sigue saliendo igual si el cero por delante

Comment: Que string estás usando?

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi solución.

```
public static String convertStringToHex(String str) {

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

        //System.out.println(hex.length());
        if (Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]).toUpperCase().length() < 2) {
            hex.append('0');
            hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]).toUpperCase());
        } else {
            hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]).toUpperCase());
        }
        hex.append(" ");
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

Resulta que la condición de que sea solo un carácter que tenias consideraba todo lo que ya llevabas en el `String` por lo tanto después de la primera iteración ya nunca iba a valer menos que 2, solucione comparando el caracter convertido y verificando que sea 1, en ese caso entonces agrega un 0 al frente y luego añade el valor `HEX`, espero que te funcione, saludos.

Comment: Me parece correcto tu lógica, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema o también es necesario hacer algún cambio en alguna propiedad del TextView?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando el metodo [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) para hacer la conversion y mantener el formateado acorde a tus necesidades.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(toHex("hello world"));

}

public static String toHex(String source){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<source.length();i++){
        builder.append(String.format("%02x ",(int)source.charAt(i)));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```